# Setting up a sftp server in node.js using ssh2 module

Tags: node.js, sftp

I would like to setup a sftp server using node.js.

I looked at [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module and seems like a good fit to start a sftp server.

I also looked at [sftp-stream api](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md), but I am not able to figure out options on how to authenticate a user to my server, which directory would be the root for sftp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an SFTP server that also handles authentication and everything (and not just an SFTP server as the subsystem for an OpenSSH server), you need to also code up the ssh2 server portion too. Here's a simple example that only allows password authentication and only starting sftp sessions:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ssh2 = require('ssh2'),
    Server = ssh2.Server;
var OPEN_MODE = ssh2.SFTP_OPEN_MODE,
    STATUS_CODE = ssh2.SFTP_STATUS_CODE;

new Server({
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync('host.key')
}, function(client) {
  console.log('Client connected!');

  client.on('authentication', function(ctx) {
    if (ctx.method === 'password'
        && ctx.username === 'foo'
        && ctx.password === 'bar')
      ctx.accept();
    else
      ctx.reject();
  }).on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client authenticated!');

    client.on('session', function(accept, reject) {
      var session = accept();
      session.on('sftp', function(accept, reject) {
        console.log('Client SFTP session');
        var openFiles = {};
        var handleCount = 0;
        // `sftpStream` is an `SFTPStream` instance in server mode
        var sftpStream = accept();
        sftpStream.on('OPEN', function(reqid, filename, flags, attrs) {
          // only allow opening /tmp/foo.txt for writing
          if (filename !== '/tmp/foo.txt' || !(flags & OPEN_MODE.WRITE))
            return sftpStream.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.FAILURE);
          // create a fake handle to return to the client, this could easily
          // be a real file descriptor number for example if actually opening
          // the file on the disk
          var handle = new Buffer(4);
          openFiles[handleCount] = true;
          handle.writeUInt32BE(handleCount++, 0, true);
          sftpStream.handle(reqid, handle);
          console.log('Opening file for write')
        }).on('WRITE', function(reqid, handle, offset, data) {
          if (handle.length !== 4 || !openFiles[handle.readUInt32BE(0, true)])
            return sftpStream.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.FAILURE);
          // fake the write
          sftpStream.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.OK);
          var inspected = require('util').inspect(data);
          console.log('Write to file at offset %d: %s', offset, inspected);
        }).on('CLOSE', function(reqid, handle) {
          var fnum;
          if (handle.length !== 4 || !openFiles[(fnum = handle.readUInt32BE(0, true))])
            return sftpStream.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.FAILURE);
          delete openFiles[fnum];
          sftpStream.status(reqid, STATUS_CODE.OK);
          console.log('Closing file');
        });
      });
    });
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
}).listen(0, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to the example code on npmjs.com for ssh2 Server Examples but a lot of time has passed so it's a bit different now: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2#server-examples